# CASE Statement in Groovy SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, groovy

I have some Groovy code that calls the groovy Sql object:

```
Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
sql.execute(insert)
```

It has worked fine in the past, but I now have some conditional logic that I tried to model with a CASE statement like `CASE WHEN a.pick = ${somevalue} THEN ${100} ELSE 0 END CASE"`

However, I get a runtime error that says it doesn't recognize `a`, but I believe it to be a symptom of the fact that it doesn't recognize the CASE statement in general, as `a` is recognized elsewhere in the query and is nothing new. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Is it a MySQL error in the stacktrace?  If so it's a problem with your SQL syntax and not grails.  Please post the SQL if the prob persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this may be an issue with your mysql syntax but I can't confirm because it is not provided.  Alternatively but, not that elegant; you could handle this with groovy...

```
def sqlInsert = "insert into foo (bar) values (${(foo.pick == someValue)? 100 : 0})"
```

**However**, first you should printing your failing query and run it in MySQL directly to see if it's a syntax issue first.